# Двунаправленные переменные через ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Есть две системы - локальная и удаленная.

На локальной системе запускаю скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

login=dev #login for ssh remote server
host=192.168.1.1 #host remote server
r_path=/home/dev/files/ #folder remote server
l_path=/home/dev/from_server #local folder
tar_name=archive.tar #archive name for files

ssh $login@$host "
cd $r_path
pwd
tar -cvf $tar_name ./*
md5sum $tar_name
"
```

Переменные со скрипта на удаленную систему передаются. Все отлично.

Получаю в вывод md5 строку удаленного архива и мне ее надо обработать на локальной системе. 
Как эту строку передать в переменной и обработать уже на локальной машине?

**UPD1:** Если я пытаюсь присвоить переменную для md5sum,

```
ssh $login@$host "
cd $r_path
tar -cvf $tar_name ./*
md5=$(md5sum $tar_name)
echo $md5
"
echo $md5
```

то она почему-то не выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём у вас возникли затруднения? Сохраняете вывод md5 в переменную и обрабатываете. И что такое - "двунаправленные переменные"?

Comment: @0xdb добавил затруднения апдейтом

Comment: Понял ваши затруднения.  Как вы себе  представили,  это невозможно. Child процесс, в данном случае ssh, ни каким образом не сможет изменить переменную окружения в parent процесс, т.е. ваш shell. Двунаправленных переменных не бывает.

Comment: Не стоило такой сложный пример приводить. Пробуйте всегда создать  [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Для вашего случая хватило бы - `~$ export myvar=1; bash -c "echo $myvar; myvar=0"; echo $myvar`.

Comment: @0xdb проблема в том, что это не пример =) я пытаюсь в скрипты.

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь сделать в скрипте, как в UPD1, достаточно воспроизвести на простом примере, как я показал в комментарии выше, чтобы понять, что так никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах работать не будет.  Ещё раз - child процесс ни каким образом не может изменить переменную в parent процесс.

Comment: @0xdb понял, спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле на удалённую систему переменные не «передаются», а подставляются на локальной машине в строку команды и уже затем вся команда отправляется на удалённый хост.

А присвоить вывод команды `ssh` переменной можно точно также как и результат любой другой команды, с помощью `$()` или же по-старинке ``` `` ```:

```
MD5_SUM="$(ssh $login@$host
  "cd $r_path && tar -cf $tar_name ./* && md5sum $tar_name"
)"
```

Замечания:

- Весь остальной вывод из команды следует убрать или перенаправить в stderr.
- Команды стоит соединять `&&`, дабы если одна из них не сработает, остальные не запускались бы.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя в самом скрипте это дописать, если он и так запускается на локальной машине? Присвоить вывод md5 в переменную и тут же обработать?

`md5forwork=$(md5sum $tar_name)`

`$md5forwork`

Если это не подходит, то я бы записывал вывод команды в отдельный файл, и уже другим скриптом подгружал и работал с ним.

Comment: Потому что архив создается на удаленной машине

Comment: добавил апдейтом проблему с данным вариантом